# Reading JSON files from curl in Python

Tags: python, json, curl

Let's say I have a command in Python that looks like

```
command = 'curl ...etc" > result.json'
subprocess.call(command, shell = True)
file = open("result.json").read()
```

What it does right now is GET from the place I curl and store the result in result.json, then I open it to read it. I wonder if there's way I can read it directly without storing to local first?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the stdlib ([json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) & [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)) to avoid the use of external commands:

```
import json
import urllib2
url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
values = json.loads(data)
```

But I'd recommend to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to simplify your code. Here a sample from the docs:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
r.status_code
200
r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
r.encoding
'utf-8'
r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

#### Python 3 Update

Please consider that in Python3 urllib2 does not exists anymore, you should use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) which comes in the standard library

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
values = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: you could skip explicit `.read()`: `values = json.load(urlopen(url))`

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you have a command that prints to its stdout then you could get the output without storing it on the disk using `subprocess.check_output`:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(['source', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```

In your case, you could use `urllib2` or `requests` Python modules instead of `curl` command as shown in [@Esparta Palma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22366829/4279).

Answer (score 1):

python3 use curl to request data 
For example, change the curl to python in the below.

```
$ curl -XPOST http://httpbin.org/post -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"attribute":"value"}'
```

intstall `urllib3`  using `$ python -m pip install urllib3`

```
import urllib3
import json
data = {'attribute': 'value'}
encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
r = http.request(
    'POST',
    'http://httpbin.org/post',
    body=encoded_data,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))['json']
```

print result

```
{'attribute': 'value'}
```

ref: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html