# Convert Python curl response.content bytes object to readable format (json, xml)

Tags: python, xml

I fetch some data from an api with below code

```py
headers = {
    'Authorization': "Basic XXXXXXXXX",
    'Accept': 'application/xml',
}

resp = requests.get('https://api_request', headers=headers)
```

I receive a correct response from the API (code 200) but content is in bytes format so not easy to read. Printing the resp.content gives:

```py
print(resp.content)
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><legalEntity xmlns="http://XXXX.io"><status>AGT_VALIDATED</status><id><code>140012</c.........
```

Is there a way to convert this in a easy to manipulate format so that I can extract the specific info I need?

Comment: You need to parse the xml : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xml-parsing-python/

Comment: This one could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366748/reading-json-files-from-curl-in-python

Comment: check out passing `resp.text` to `xml.etree.ElementTree`. See also [How to read xml file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351894/how-to-read-xml-file-using-python)

Comment: If response is JSON as suggested in the title use `response.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. Below the solution I went for.

```py
mydict = xmltodict.parse(resp.content.decode('utf-8'))
```